Find names from a list in cell with text
I have one column with text inputs (Longname) and I need to check if these inputs contain names from another list (short name).
If so, I need the formula to produce the matched 'short name' in the output cell. The lists are rather long (+200 entries) so I can't put each individual name in the formula. Does anyone know know how to do this? Thanks!

I tried various Lookups, Search, and Match but can't get it right. Please help.

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.
